# Is there a way to return items from an array after a certain time using date-fns or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datetime, date-fns

I am currently using the `date-fns` library in my Angular application and I am using the helper called `isWeekend` to return some time slot items from an array that only fall on a weekend.

However, I can't find a way to return the Weekend items after a certain time such as 'after 1pm'.

Please see below:

- There are two dates with a time after 13:00:00 (1 PM)
- There are two dates with a time before 13:00:00 (1 PM)

I need to adjust my filter to accommodate for the times which are **after 13:00:00 (1 PM)** and on the **weekend**.

```js
const days = [
  { date: "Sun Jul 25 2020 15:30:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)" },
  { date: "Sun Jul 25 2020 19:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)" },
  { date: "Sat Jul 25 2020 05:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)" },
  { date: "Sat Jul 25 2020 02:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)" }
];

const filteredDays = days.filter((day) => {
  console.log(dateFns.isWeekend(day.date));
  // Need a solution for dateFns.isWeekend and after 13:00:00 or 1 PM
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.30.1/date_fns.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the 'hours' component of the date with the same library's `getHours` function, and then see if the number it returns is 13 or higher. Combined with your existing usage of `isWeekend`, your filter is quite simple.

Note: This library is going to run both of those functions based on the user's current locale, while your dates are specifying a timezone. Just something to keep in mind.

```js
const days = [
  { date: "Sun Jul 25 2020 15:30:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)" },
  { date: "Sun Jul 25 2020 19:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)" },
  { date: "Sat Jul 25 2020 05:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)" },
  { date: "Sat Jul 25 2020 02:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)" }
];

const filteredDays = days.filter((day) => {
 return dateFns.isWeekend(day.date) && dateFns.getHours(day.date) >= 13;
});

console.log(filteredDays);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.30.1/date_fns.min.js"></script>
```